# previewer for xhtml containing jsf and primefaces tags

Tags: jsf, primefaces, preview

I am developing an xhtml editor. It will be used for files with primefaces and core jsf tags. I want to have a preview feature for this editor. It can be  a rough preview or exact preview. I am not sure about the approach that can be used for this feature. Any pointer to the approach or suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!